# Border Outside of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to set border to linearLayout without modifying it's size, I try setting in the background of linearLayout some drawable with border and padding but this one is set inside of the linearLayout and modifies size, image and textView. Do you have a way of setting border outside of view or superpose views?

My Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemCarouselContainer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/carousel_item_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/carousel_item_margin_right"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageCarousel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/carousel_image_poster_height"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/live"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/carouse_item_live_margin_left"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/carousel_item_live_margin_top"
            android:padding="@dimen/carousel_item_live_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/carousel_live_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/carousel_item_live_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleCarousel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/carousel_content_title_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/carousel_content_title_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/carousel_title_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **NO**. You can't add anything **outside** a View (unless you add a container View to it), only **inside** it. Possibly, `padding` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this as a drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">

  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@color/miniBlack"
      android:dashGap="10px"
      android:dashWidth="10px"/>
</shape>
```

Set it as background of your layout giving it a `2dp padding` so the `stroke` won't override the content

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemCarouselContainer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/carousel_item_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/carousel_item_margin_right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/myfile"
    android:paddings="2dp"
 >...
```